# Delphi SQlite login procedure crash

Tags: sqlite, delphi

been trying to figure out why the following login authentication procedure doesn't work.  I have a simple database table holding pupilID and password (in tblPupil) It seems to connect ok upon compilation i.e. that is procedure Connection, but when i run procedure Login...the program seems to crash. In fact, i get no error messages which could illuminate me further! Could this be a database driver problem?
(Using Delphi7, SQLite Database with DevartSQLiteDirect driver)

```pascal
Procedure TForm1.Connection;
begin
 SQLConnection1.Params.Add('Database=C:\SQLite\PupilDatabase');
  try
    // Establish the connection.
    SQLConnection1.Connected := true;
    label4.Caption := 'OK!';
  except
    on E: EDatabaseError do
      ShowMessage('Exception raised with message' + E.Message);
  end;
end;

Procedure TForm1.UserLogin;
var QueryPass : string;
    Lcount : String;
    cont : boolean;
begin
cont := false;
if InputID.Text = '' then
ShowMessage('Invalid Pupil ID')
else begin
      cont := True;
While cont = True do
begin
  // A random query
  QueryPass := 'SELECT password FROM TblPupil Where pupilID = +InputID.Text+';';
  try
  // Assign the query to the object SQLQuery1.
    SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := QueryPass;
    SQLQuery1.open;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Exception raised with message: ' + E.Message);
  end;
SQLQuery1.First;
Lcount := SQLQuery1.FieldValues['password'];
 if Lcount = InputPass.text then
  begin
     Form1.Hide;
     Form16.show;
  end
 else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Wrong');
    cont := false;
  end;
   Form1.Hide;
   Form16.show;       
end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the `UserLogin` code?

Comment: only a typo ?? Your query is nonsens. `QueryPass := 'SELECT password FROM TblPupil Where pupilID = +InputID.Text+';` It means `pupilID` must be equal to a string with pluses `+` and a text  `InputID.Text` . Im shure that is not what you want .  The right Query should look like : `QueryPass := 'SELECT password FROM TblPupil Where pupilID =''' +InputID.Text+ ''';' ;` Or if field pupilID is an integer then :  `QueryPass := 'SELECT password FROM TblPupil Where pupilID =' +InputID.Text+ ';' ;`

Answer (score 2):

Your query is nonsense. As it's written now, it will not even compile (you have unterminated quotes at the right side), much less execute (because `WHERE pupilID = + Input.Text +' is invalid SQL syntax).

Get out of the habit of concatenating SQL immediately, before you even start, and learn to use parameterized queries. Doing so prevents SQL injection, and allows the database driver to properly do conversions of data types and properly quote values when needed so you don't have to do so.

```
SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT password from TblPupil'#13 +
                      'WHERE pupilID = :pupilID';
SQLQuery1.ParamByName('pupilID').AsString := InputID.Text;
SQLQuery1.Open;
```

With that being said, the rest of the code in your `UserLogin` procedure is pretty bad as well. It's cluttered with unnecessary variables, it has invalid logic (regardless of whether the username and password match, you end up hiding Form1 and showing Form6, which defeats the entire purpose of logging in, AFAICT). You might try something like this instead:

```
Procedure TForm1.UserLogin;
var 
  UserPass: string;
begin
  if InputID.Text = '' then
    raise Exception.Create('You must enter a Pupil ID.');

  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT password from TblPupil'#13 +
                        'WHERE pupilID = :pupilID';
  SQLQuery1.ParamByName('pupilID').AsString := InputID.Text;
  try
    SQLQuery1.Open;
    if SQLQuery1.IsEmpty then
      raise Exception.Create('Invalid Pupil ID or password.');
    UserPass := SQLQuery1.FieldValues['password'];
  finally
    SQLQuery1.Close;
  end;

 if UserPass = InputPass.text then
 begin
     Form1.Hide;
     Form16.show;
  end
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid Pupil ID or password.');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be the fact that form16 is not created yet. However, more importantly, you need to get delphi stopping when it hits an exception. I suspect you have accidentally turned it off.
Depending on your version of Delphi it may be
menu/Options/Debugger Options then choose Stop on Delphi Exceptions.

Note also that the 'first' operation fails on an empty dataset so defensively you should have an 'bof' check in there in case the inputid is invalid.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should do something like this (from the code I used in one application):

```
    procedure TForm4.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    LOGIN_QUERY.Active:=false;
    LOGIN_QUERY.SQL.Clear;
    LOGIN_QUERY.SQL.Add('select user,password,from users where user='+QuotedStr(cxlookupcombobox1.text)+' and password='+QuotedStr(cxTextEdit1.Text));
    LOGIN_QUERY.Open;
    if LOGIN_QUERY.FieldByName('Password').AsString<>''
    then  Form16.Show   else  
    ShowMessage('Wrong Password');
    end;
```

Though your code is a little fussy, I dont understand how comes your table contains only pupilID and a password. Should not there be a pupil name too?

Comment: Can you please check my favorite password `''; delete from users;` with your application?

Comment: Thank you  for your many replies...I am currently re-working the solution in light of your responses.  I will update progress shortly. Thanks